# PHP post textarea separately

Tags: php

The problem I am facing is:

```
if(isset($_POST ['textarea1']));
```

Is there a way in which I am able to only Post `textarea1`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need 15 forms, or to use javascript

Comment: is there a reason why you're trying to post 1 at a time? you can just post all 15, and just process the first one. or use AJAX to post one at a time. or have 15 different forms, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: The thing is that I am using Xpath to grab information from documents, and I have the xpath code currently in Foreach loops, which is why I need to post the textareas seperately as almost each textarea points to a different document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to post a specific element is if the `<form>` had only that element in it.

The only other way would be to write a Javascript function, hook it `onSubmit` of that `<form>` element, do whatever you want, and `return false`.